# 'angular package is missing' when running 'meteor test'

Tags: angularjs, meteor, mocha.js, angular-meteor

I'm trying to create some tests for my Meteor app using `practicalmeteor:mocha` however I run into `angular package is missing` when loading the page.

Command I am running to start:

```
meteor test --driver-package practicalmeteor:mocha --port 3100
```

Angular is imported in my main js file and running the Meteor app normally works fine. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Off the top of my head you may need to do an npm install -g mocha

Comment: I'm guessing again, but I suspect that meteor package wasn't written with Angular in mind. So your challenge might be how to initialise/load Angular. Can you turn on some debug output to get a better idea of what it is trying to do? Is there any more info in the console?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running,

npm install eslint

Checkout more details in https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint